# Out of Memory issue when multiple visitors view product catalog

Tags: php

First question, so sorry if I do something wrong!

My issue is, I have a product catalog, which displays up to 18 thumbnails, each approx 6kb, in a product catalog. Each of the thumbnails calls a script get_db_image which searches for and returns the image relating to the product. Simple, so far. The issue only arises when approx 3 or 4 requests are made at the same time for a product catalog page, each user is expecting 18 thumbnails and details to be returned, but when they all do it at the same time I get out of memory errors and sometimes the server crashes. I've stripped down the code that retrieves and displays the image, and the hosting people have raised the memory limit to 256M, but it's all to no avail. As far as I can tell I'm destroying the images I've created and the virtual memory goes back to zero split seconds after the requests are made, but at the peak all the memory is being utilised, hence the crashes, so the only thing I can think off doing is getting, displaying and destroying each image before I start the next one, but I don't know how to go about that, but maybe there is a better solution? Please help, pulling my hair out and I don't have a lot to waste!

```
    // executes the query searching for the image
$res = execPDORetRes($query, $vars);

// if there is no image, load a default
if(sizeof($res) == 0)
{
    $query_parts = explode(" ", $query);
    $query = "select * from ".$query_parts[3]." where id = :id";
    $vars = array(':id-int' => 1);
    $res = execPDORetRes($query, $vars);    
}
$data = $res[0];

// create the image from the DB
$img = imagecreatefromstring($data[$name]); 

$type = "image/pjpeg";

Header( "Content-type: image/pjpeg"); 

$width = imagesx($img); 
$height = imagesy($img);

// if the image is too big
if($size_w != $width || $size_h != $height)
{
    // set widths and heights
    if ($width <= $size_w) 
    {
        $new_w = $width;
        $new_h = $height;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $new_w = $size_w;
        $new_h = $size_h;
    }

    // create a new image of the specified width and height
    $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h); 

    // resize the original 
    imagecopyresized($new_img,$img,0,0,0,0,$new_w,$new_h,$width,$height);

    // determine image type and send it to the client    
    imagejpeg($new_img,"","80"); 

    // clear the image from memory
    imagedestroy($new_img); 
    imagedestroy($img);         
    unset($width, $height, $new_h, $new_w, $new_img, $img);
}
else
{
    // if the image is smaller than or the right size
    // determine image type and send it to the client    
    imagejpeg($img,"","80"); 

    // clear the image from memory
    imagedestroy($img); 
    unset($width, $height, $img);
}

ob_flush();
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you generating images on every request? Why not do it once when you create the product or upload images and then just provide already cached versions?

Comment: Hi N.B., would a cached copy of the images not hog even more memory constantly? The shop has over 1500 products at present each with their own main image and thumbnail.

Comment: Well, you're running out of memory because on each request php is forced to do work with images, which is memory expensive. Since cached versions would require PHP to do that work once instead of every time - yes, that would be much easier on the server. The only issue would be to store images somewhere on the hard drive which shouldn't be a problem seeing that storage space is super cheap these days.

Comment: So, on upload the image is copied into a folder on the hard drive, a path to that image would be written to the database, when the product catalog is referenced the script looks up the db for the location and reads the file from there. This means the only image functions are if I want to resize the image on upload, so do my resizing there then save to directory, then it's a straight <img src link to the file. Have I got that right?

Comment: Exactly like you wrote it :)

Comment: And I can actually save space on the hard drive by only doing this with the thumbnail images, the main images are only displayed 1 per page, so shouldn't cause an issue - or would you do them all?

Comment: I'd generate all of them, space isn't really an issue in this day and age.

Comment: Appreciate the help - I'll give this a go and see how I get on. Thanks. - I've no way of giving you a vote!?

Comment: Bogdan suggested the same thing, you should accept his answer. I'm fine with people getting on and doing their work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should generate your thumbnails in advance if you want to this it this way. 
This means you should have your normal product images under e.g. "public/images/products/main" and then your thumbs under "public/images/products/thumbs" and then store in the database your paths to the product images and your thumbs.

This approach is better then creating them on the fly.

Otherwise you could just scale them down with css, if bandwidth is not a problem, but I guess it is.

You can even keep your thumbs script and check in the db if a thumbnail exists, if it does not, call your script: generate thumb, save thumb, update db. The next time a user comes and you need to display this thumbnail, it will already be there.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, as I asked N.B. above, would this approach not use more memory if all the product images were cached for quick retrieval?

Comment: Depends on the caching. For instance memcached and apc use memory to fasten things up, but you also have the option of using a disk cache.

Regardless, this will use less memory compared to generating images on the fly every time.

Answer (score 0):

256 megabytes should be plenty. Nothing in your code looks bad and you're even using `unset`. I recommend debugging with Xdebug and WinCacheGrind, they can produce in-depth logs...

[image]

Comment: I've asked the hosting people for XDebug to be enabled on the server, they enabled it then told me I wouldn't have access to the results as it's a shared host, so I can't actually see the profiling info. Thanks for getting back!